# How to preview animated png image on Mac?

Tags: macos, animation, png

I've google this question "How to preview animated png image on Mac?" , but all the answer is How to preview animated "gif", but I'm asking preview an animated png image, not animated gif,I've tried the QuickLook on Mac, but it looks like the animated png is just a static png, and the only app(on my Mac) I found that can preview animated png is a Browser(both Chrome and Safari can do), but I am trying to find something like QuickLook plugin to support previewing an animated png by QuickLook.

[how to preview animated png image on Mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1G98.png)

Comment: Try using a web-browser to preview one - Safari, Chrome, Firefox.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you, I already know this, it seems that a web-broswer is the only way to preview animated png

Comment: It's as you say. It doesn't work with Quicklook, but it works with your browser. Maybe you could create your own Quicklook plugin for this, but that would be much work for a little feature (unless you wrote a Quicklook plugin yourself before). If you're looking for a trick (like go to terminal and "defaults write ...") - that does not exist.

Comment: @Michael Thank you Michael, I wish I could write a Quicklook plugin, but I can't